# How can I expose some static content (jpg images) using Carbon server?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am not so into **WSO2 Carbon** and maybe it is a trivial question.

I am using **WSO2 ESB** (included into **WSO2 EI**) to deploy some APIs into **Carbon**.

From what I know **Carbon** should be based on **Tomcat**.

So I am asking: is it possible to deploy and expose on Internet not only my APIs but also some static content (some jpg images) using Carbon?

Do you have some idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's based on Tomcat and you can deploy web application on it. You have to put your webapp to following location.

```
<WSO2_HOME>/repository/deployments/server/webapps/
```

Comment: Thank you. So I can deploy web app into this folder...but have I to create a web app to deploy and make accessible only JPG images? Or can I do something easier? Thank you

Comment: Try https://www.moreofless.co.uk/static-content-web-pages-images-tomcat-outside-war/